# How to remove some sort of constraint?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, constraints

Okay, so I downloaded a .blend of Tux Penguin, but because I'm too dumb to know how to remove some sort of transform lock thing that came with the model, I can't rig it the way I want to. For some bones, it is impossible to transform them, and attempting to do so will result in switching tools to the rotate tool instead.
How do I remove these locks?

[This is the problem.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l00ps54xzf2yk7u/Penguin.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Afais there are no constraints or locks in this rig. The bones are just parented. You can un-parent them in edit mode of the armature (Alt P). There is also a vertex group missing for "Spine".

Answer (score 1):

2 things : the first being constraints , Remove them for full accessibility.

[image]

The second being transform locks , They are in the objects tab. Make sure they are all deselected / unlocked

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the file the OP uploaded? I didn't see any constraints or transform locks in use.

Comment: Yeah, um... did you look at the file? This would normally work, but not with this.

Comment: User2849 had the answer actually.

Comment: I didnt see the link to the .blend . I missed it